# Xcode 6 Beta UIWebView Cannot read .rtf

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rtf, ios8, xcode6

Console message: 2014-08-09 15:51:37.526 Agpeya[1306:29686] Cannot find data converter callback for uti public.rtf

Answer (score 2):

From the [iOS 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/)

> **Known Issue**
>
> RTF file support in UIWebView is broken.
>
> Workaround: Show RTF files to the user is to use the Quick Look
>   framework (QLPreviewController) or to load an NSAttributedString from
>   the RTF file and show it in an UITextView, which will render the
>   content in a much cleaner way.

I assume they will fix this in an upcoming release.  One would hope.

Comment: Looks like this bug made it into the release version! :/

Answer (score 2):

Update your Xcode to 6.1, this issue is fixed in iOS 8.1. You can test it by running in iOS 8.1 simulator.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Although i don't see any documentation for this, this might be a beta version bug.

worth waiting a while and see if it got fixed.

BTW, applications like Adobe Acrobat also fail to open rtf files on iOS8 beta 5, so it makes sense that this is a bug.
The other option is that apple has stopped supporting this type, which sound very unlikely.

EDIT: seems that apple stopped supporting viewing these types natively. It doesn't work on the official iOS release too.

Answer (score 1):

From the iOS 8 Release notes this is a known issue:

*Workaround: Show RTF files to the user is to use the Quick Look framework (QLPreviewController) or to load an NSAttributedString from the RTF file and show it in an UITextView, which will render the content in a much cleaner way.*

I assume that they will eventually fix the issue. I tried both QLPreviewController and a UITextView with an NSAttributedString and they both worked.

Answer (score 1):

Note - Reading RTF files by UIWebview broken -   This issue will be **fixed with iOS 8.1**

See iOS 8.1 Release Notes from Apple
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/

Search for 
Fixed in iOS 8.1 Beta
RTF file support in UIWebView is broken

Comment: Except that it isn't fixed in iOS 8.1

Comment: IOS 8.1 is in beta mode and yet to be rekeased... On running with xcode 6.1 GM seed on iOS 8.1 simulator I found this issue fixed.. Pls check

Comment: I know it works in the simulator, but the important thing is what happens on the device. I'll try it on the device and report back.

Comment: Okay, RTF now does work on the device in 8.1. But rtfd (compressed as .rtfd.zip) does not, whereas it does for a UIWebView in iOS 7 and before.